# How to filter a list by comparing a value from another list using Linq in C#?

Tags: c#, list, linq, collections, compare

I have a list of `Fruit` which has name and price value.

```
public class Fruit {
    public string name {get; set;}
    public int price {get; set;}

    public Fruit(string n, int p)
    {
            name = n;
            price = p;
    }
    ...
}

List<Fruit> myBasket = new List<Fruit>();
myBasket.Add(new Fruit("apple", 300));
myBasket.Add(new Fruit("banana", 200));
myBasket.Add(new Fruit("kiwi", 400));
```

Also, there is a list of average market price of fruits.

```
List<Fruit> averagePrice = new List<Fruit>();
averagePrice.Add(new Fruit("apple", 500));
averagePrice.Add(new Fruit("banana", 100));
averagePrice.Add(new Fruit("kiwi", 600));
```

What I want to do is to filter myBasket to have only fruit that is lower price than averagePrice.

So, in the example, myBasket will have apple and kiwi.

I tried `myBasket = myBasket.Where(v => v.price < averagePrice.FirstOrDefault(y => y.name.Equals(v.name)).price).ToList();`.

It works well, but has a possibility of null pointer exception when there is new fruit in `myBasket` but not in `averagePrice`.

How can I change it to prevent it from exception?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be quite a simple way to do it:

```
myBasket =
(
    from f in myBasket
    join a in averagePrice on f.name equals a.name
    where f.price < a.price
    select f
).ToList();
```

That gives me:

[image]

---

Here's the equivalent method-syntax:

```
myBasket =
    myBasket
        .Join(averagePrice, f => f.name, a => a.name, (f, a) => new { f, a })
        .Where(x => x.f.price < x.a.price)
        .Select(x => x.f)
        .ToList();
```

Comment: I must study joins... What about if the banana is not in the average list ? Take it or not take it ?

Comment: I think, banana won't be taken when join because it is not in averagePrice?

Comment: @OlivierRogier - It won't take it. The join must have both sides equal. You can do a left outer join with `join a in averagePrice on f.name equals a.name into g` and then `g` can contain zero or more matches. That would be a `GroupJoin`.

Comment: @Enigmativity I must study joins one day... I understand nothing :)

Comment: @Enigmativity what if I make a query using lambda expression?

Comment: @W.Cointreau - That would be fine too. The query syntax is just syntactic sugar.